# Opening a new window from asp.net chart control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, charts

I am firing JS window.open command from the asp.net chart control but that is not getting fired up.

Below is the code of an .aspx page that would build a pyramid.

```
<div>

        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="416px" ImageType="Jpeg" 
        Width="525px" IsMapAreaAttributesEncoded="True" Palette="None" 
        PaletteCustomColors="Navy; DarkBlue; DarkBlue; DarkBlue; DarkBlue; DarkBlue; DarkBlue" 
        TextAntiAliasingQuality="SystemDefault" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series BackGradientStyle="DiagonalRight" BackSecondaryColor="Black" 
                BorderColor="Black" ChartType="Pyramid" Color="Transparent" 
                CustomProperties="Pyramid3DRotationAngle=8, PyramidMinPointHeight=60, PyramidPointGap=3, PyramidLabelStyle=Inside" 
                Font="Verdana, 8pt, style=Bold" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Name="Series1" 
                ShadowColor="Black" LabelForeColor="White" Palette="Grayscale">
                <Points>
                    <asp:DataPoint CustomProperties="PyramidInsideLabelAlignment=Top" 
                        Label="             xxxxxx                               Column-1"
                        ToolTip="1111" YValues="40"/>
                    <asp:DataPoint CustomProperties="PyramidInsideLabelAlignment=Top" 
                        Label="xxxxxx                         Column-2" MapAreaAttributes="" ToolTip="2222"
                        YValues="40" />
                    <asp:DataPoint CustomProperties="PyramidInsideLabelAlignment=Top" 
                        Label="xxxxxx                   Column-3" MapAreaAttributes="" ToolTip="" Url="" 
                        YValues="40" />
                    <asp:DataPoint CustomProperties="PyramidInsideLabelAlignment=Top" 
                        Label="     xxxxxx              Col4" MapAreaAttributes="" ToolTip="" Url="" 
                        YValues="40"  />
                    <asp:DataPoint 
                        Label="  xxxxxx          Col5" MapAreaAttributes="" ToolTip="" Url="" 
                        YValues="40"  />
                    <asp:DataPoint Label="  xxxxxx    Col6" MapAreaAttributes="onClick='javascript:OpenPage();'" ToolTip="" Url="" 
                        YValues="40" />
                    <asp:DataPoint CustomProperties="PyramidInsideLabelAlignment=Bottom" 
                        Label="xx Col7" MapAreaAttributes="" ToolTip="" Url="" YValues="40" />
                </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" IsRightAngleAxes="False" Perspective="30" 
                    Inclination="45" PointGapDepth="1000" Rotation="60" />
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>    

    </div>
```

Below is the code behind;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string statusClicked = string.Empty;
            Series series = new Series("MySeries");
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pyramid;
            series.BorderWidth = 3;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Column-1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-3.", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-4", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-5", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-6", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column-7", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(1400, 2240, 7660, 3410, 15, 4, 9);
            int colCount = dt.Columns.Count;
            List<string> xaxis = new List<string>();
            List<double> yaxis = new List<double>();

          Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');\"";

         }
```

Ideally, on the click of any series in the chart, google link should get open and status assigned wouldbe the one obtained from code. But the code never works.

The URL that it opens is something like;

```
http://localhost:1450/javascript%3avar+win%3dwindow.open('http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%3fstatus%3dTestStatus')%3b
```

here as you can see that the status is Test Status and so the link that should open is http://www.google.com/?status=TestStatus

NOTE: the labelURL property would take  URL only.

Comment: Is window.open syntax written in code snippet 1 correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can use the MapAreaAttributes. 
Something like;

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points[i].LabelUrl = "http://www.google.co.in?status=" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
series.MapAreaAttributes = "target=\"_blank\"";
```

or you can do something like (without querystring);

```
        foreach (Series series in Chart1.Series)
        {
            series.MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');\"";
        }
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.maparea.mapareaattributes.aspx) is more info on the keywords that can help with your querystring parameter passing.

In your case, you can also use MapAreaAttributes for the DataPointCollection

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points[i].MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.co.in?status=" + dtSample.Columns[4].ColumnName.ToString() + "');\"";
```

Comment: I need to open the window using window.open javascript and hence first code wouldn't be eligible (even if that works). hence i am testing with the second code snippet

Comment: the second code snippet doesn't works. Any other solution that could be implemented?

Comment: i tested this and it works; series.MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');\""; Also if you want to pass the querystring take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.maparea.mapareaattributes.aspx

Comment: how did you tested this? i mean could you post little bit more code please?

Comment: I had created a column graph and for my series i added this to the code behind and when i click on the series it opens up a new window with the defined url.
            foreach (Series series in Chart1.Series)
            {
                series.MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');\"";
            } 
Like i said though, if you want to have specific arguments passed regarding the series or labels etc. you will need to have keywords such as #SER, #VALX, #VALY, #LABEL etc.

Comment: i am not very sure how your code works! please post a full detailed code

Comment: i edited my answer above and added a code piece to the end. I tried this; without the dtsample since i don't know what that is so i replaced it with a variable i created; and it opens a new window with the variable i am passing.

Comment: Hello zero7, i have updated the question with the code i have been using (& trying to get the desired result).. Please see into this and just let me know what am i missing that is stopping from opening a popup.. Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: please guide.. i am stuck up with this one issue

Comment: Try removing IsMapAreaAttributesEncoded="True" from your chart properties in your code. Also remove mapareaattributes from design and add them to all points in the code behind like this              
foreach (var point in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
            {
                point.MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');\"";
            }
    Hope this helps.